# Regex with variables in it

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9]){1,8}$/
```

This is a normal way to write a regex in JavaScript but I want to construct the regex dynamically with a variable in between ().

`Variable = [A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: What do you mean with a variable in between?

Comment: tell us an example of what does this regex.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can build a new regular expression from string:

```js
var v = '[A-Za-z0-9]';
var regExp = new RegExp('^(' + v + '){1,8}$');
console.log(regExp);
```

Now you can use the regular expression `regExp` in your purpose